# Scala map casting issues: type mistmatch

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, type-mismatch

I have the following Scala function:

```
def processMaps(toProcess : Map[Object,Object]) : Unit = {
  // The 'toProcess' map might have a key named 'innerMap' which is itself a Map[String,String]
  // Compiler Error: type mismatch; found : Object required: (String, String)
  val innerMap : Map[String,String] = if (toProcess.containsKey("innerMap")) Map(toProcess.get("innerMap")) else null

  // Do stuff to 'innerMap'...
}
```

The problem is that the `innerMap` declaration produces the following compiler error:

> type mismatch; found : Object required: (String, String)

Any idea why and what the fix is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toProcess.get("innerMap")` returns an object, and you are trying to create a Map[String,String] from an object, that makes no sense

you could (but you shouldn't because it can throw exceptions in runtime) force a type cast with:

```
toProcess.get("innerMap").asInstanceOf[Map[String, String]]
```

there are several details in your code that are not the best:

1. a `Map[Object,Object]` ? you should make the key and values more type specific. Why do you have such a generic type? Are you mixing very different types? That's not idiomatic Scala. At least have a Map[String, Map]
2. If it's a Scala Map (and not a Java Map), the `Map.get` method would return an `Option`. You can do `.getOrElse(defaultValue)`, or instead of `Map.get` do a `Map.getOrElse(key, defaultValue)`
3. Scala avoids the usage of `null`s. Instead it uses `Option` to encapsulate possible unexistent values, and then typical (monad) functions like `.map` to apply some function/behaviour if the value is present

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possible solution. Pattern matching is your friend and avoids the asInstanceOf which feels a little brittle.

```
def processMaps(toProcess : Map[Object,Object]) : Unit = {
    val maybeObject: Option[Object] = toProcess.get("innerMap")
    maybeObject.foreach {
      case inner: Map[String, String] => // do some stuff to inner
        Unit
      case _ => // do nothing
        Unit
    }
}
```

Or even less code

```
def processMaps(toProcess : Map[Object,Object]) : Unit = {
    toProcess.get("innerMap").foreach {
       case inner: Map[String, String] => // do some stuff to inner
       case _ => // do nothing
    }
}
```

A couple of things here.

1. Using pattern matching is less error prone
2. foreach is preferred for code that returns Unit.